# Catalan's number with a twist

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

We all know that

$$C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} {2n \choose n} $$

But what if I want to calculate the same property of catalan, but with number of zeros is $s$ and number of ones is $t$ when $s\neq t$?
As in:

> Calculate in how many binary sequences with length of $s+t$ there are exactly $s$ zeros, and in all sub-sequences the number of ones ($t$) is not greater than the number of zeros ($t\leq s$)?

In my opinion, to calculate this we might need to assign a function $F: \text{group of all bad sequences} \longrightarrow \text{group of all binary sequences of s+1 ones and t-1 
zeros}$

But I have no idea on how to go on!

Comment: In the interest of making the question more accessible, it would be nice to mention *the particular way that the Catalan numbers enumerate certain binary sequences* that you are asking to generalize.

Answer (score 2):

This is the generalization (or perhaps the original formulation) of [Bertrand's Ballot Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9%27s_reflection_method). The number of such paths is given by the reflection principle and is
$$C_{s,\ t} = \frac{s-t+1}{s+1}\binom{s+t}{t}$$
Notice that when $s=t=n$ then we recover the original Catalan numbers
$$C_{n,n}=C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9%27s_reflection_method#Variant:_ties_allowed
This is the part I am actually looking for, but where can I find a more detailed proof using the method they used?

Comment: @EuYu I think that there is a mistake in the last equation. Shouldn't the denominator be n + 1?

Comment: @pkacprzak Yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing it out.